# Navigation Drawer in flavoured Android

Tags: android

I am using navigation drawer and it works fine in native android devices but stutters in opening and closing in flavoured android devices. I have made my drawer consulting this(http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) example. It works fine for both types of devices when implemented independently but in my app it stutters for flavoured devices.
Also it stops stuttering as soon as I remove the adapter. Again stuttering is happening on only flavoured devices like samsung, mi etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting android:alpha attribute in layout of the row of drawer which was causing problem in flavoured android.